# Weirdly I can't ping my Gateway from linux virtual machines

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, vmware, kerio

**Assume the following Situations:**

- Gateway IP : `10.0.0.60`
- Host IP (Win7) : `10.0.0.81`
- Guest 1 on this Host (VMWare-Linux-Kali) : `10.0.0.16`
- Guest 2 on this Host (VMWare-Win7) : `10.0.0.27`
- Gateway is a Kerio server.

**The Problem:**

I can't ping the gateway from Kali-Linux virtual machine, while I can ping it from both Host and Win7 virtual machine!

**Configuration:**

- All the firewalls for Host and guests are off.
- Guests can successfully ping each other and also ping the Host!
- Host can ping both guests successfully!
- Network Adabpter settings for both guests are equal and the only difference is their IP.
- Network adapters of virtual machines are bridged with the host network adapter.

**What am I did so far?**

- I replaced Kali-linux guest IP address with Win7 guest IP address (and vice-versa). Well, nothing changed!
- I tried other operation systems as guest. For Ubuntu and Backtrack I can't ping the Gateway too, but for Win7 and Win XP it is ok.
- I run *Wireshark* on my host and monitor the traffic. Well, I can see ICMP request packets for both Linux guests and windows guests, but the reply from Gateway are for Windows guest only.

**Unstable solution:**

In the past when I face with this problem, manipulating the route table on Linux virtual machine was solved the issue (50%-50%), but now it doesn't work any more!

**Settings:**

My Host:

```
C:\Users\asdf.IT>ipconfig -all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : asdf-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : it.com
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : it.com

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-60-6E-70-4C-E4
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::6079:96ba:2ea2:18e9%11(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.81(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.60
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 235429998
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-B7-B0-8E-08-60-6E-70-4C-E4

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.10
                                       8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet
1
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-01
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::45cc:c483:1d0a:a9a%17(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.227.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 218124374
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-B7-B0-8E-08-60-6E-70-4C-E4

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet
8
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-08
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::19cc:79f0:bc05:ce97%18(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.153.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 251678806
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-B7-B0-8E-08-60-6E-70-4C-E4

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{1FD7A0A9-BE6F-44F9-8BA7-E7E0043D4B36}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{41D1949E-CADB-47E2-BBDC-F907E48DBA03}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Win 7 guest (On VMware):
[image]

Kali Linux guest (On VMware):
[image]

**Does anyone have any idea what is the origin of this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routing table is correct, actually it is identical to mine.

But you state:

> I run Wireshark on my host and monitor the traffic. Well, I can see ICMP request packets for both Linux guests and windows guests, but the reply from Gateway are for Windows guest only.

This means your gateway is responding differently to the two ping packets. The best way to proceed is to capture both packets and to compare them.  Since you are running  wireshark, listen on the Host outbound interface, restrict your capture to the `icmp` protocol and to destination `10.0.60.0`, ping once only from host1 nd host2, save the 2 packets to a file, study what is different between them.

The difference between the two packets is what is triggering the different gateway behavior. **If**, at the end, the only difference is the source IP address, then it means there is a problem with your kali Ip address. If it is a static address make sure it is outside the DHCP range. If not you may try restarting gateway, host and VMs to ensure the release of the DHCP leases, in case of conflict with previously assigned addresses.

Comment: Wow! I checked **ARP** tables on  my operation systems. In the linux guest a wrong MAC address is assigned to the Gateway and when I statically assign the correct MAC to it, everything works fine! I filter the traffic for the ARP protocol, and I found that somebody say <ThisWrongMAC> is MAC of Gateway only for ARP "Who has" requests of linux!

Comment: @TheGoodUser Be careful, this behavior is what is called `ARP spoofing`, and it is one of the elementary hacking techniques. You'd better investigate this issue.

Comment: Well, you are right, I know ARP poisoning technique. But it wasn't a malware or attack. I finally found that the wrong MAC is MAC address of second network adapter of my Gateway! It is a really weird behavior, because My host and virtual machines are not in the same network of second network adapter of gateway! As gateway is a VM installed on ESX and its network adapters are virtual, I think it must be a bug in ESX. Maybe I asked the issue on a new question. Thank you for the alert :)

Answer (score 0):

I had an almost identical problem (Google brought me here) but in my case the issue was the the VM configuration had somehow changed from Bridged (assigned to it's own NIC) to NAT, hence the VM kept thinking it had an IP address allocated by VMWare's virtual bridge, despite me having modified /etc/networking/interfaces and restarted the network service....

In hindsight, I can't think how the network settings could change within VMWare, so I'm more inclined to think it was my mistake, but I could have sworn I set the VM to 'bridged' before starting up the Kali VMDK....