# Linux Virtual machine can't ping Google, while Host can do it

Tags: linux, networking, ping, vmware-workstation, icmp

**Assumptions:**

1. You have a Windows 7 Ultimate as your host.
2. You have a Linux Kali 2 as a VMWare Workstation virtual machine on this host.
3. Your network adapter is bridged on the VMWare(Version 10.0.3).
4. Host IP address = `10.0.0.81`
5. Virtual Machine IP address = `10.0.0.38`
6. Host Gateway = `10.0.0.60`
7. Virtual machine Gateway = `10.0.0.60`
8. Virtual Machine and Host can ping each other and also the gateway successfully.

**Problem:**

While Host can ping `46.228.47.114` (Yahoo) successfully, the virtual machine can't! In the other words, `ICMP requests` from host to Yahoo, have `ICMP reply` packets, but `ICMP requests` from the virtual machine haven't!

**What am I did so far?**

1. I replaced my host IP address with the virtual machine IP address, and vice versa, but nothing changed.
2. I tried other virtual machines. For all Linux virtual machines I have this issue, while all Windows virtual machines are working fine!
3. I tried different versions of VMware® Workstation and VMWare VSphere softwares. Issue doesn't solved for my Linux virtual machines.

**Differences between ICMP requests:**

*Windows 7:*

[image]

*Kali Linux:*
[image]

As you see above, there are some difference between requests. Is these difference origin of the problem? If so, how can I handle it?

**Note that:**

Formerly I even [can't ping the Gateway on the Virtual Machine](https://superuser.com/questions/997636/weirdly-i-cant-ping-my-gateway-from-linux-virtual-machines)! By sniffing I noticed that MAC address of gateway in the Virtual machine is not correct, so I set it statically with the correct value and after that I pinged it successfully. Now this is the new problem!

**Update:**

I'm just see that I have Internet access on the virtual machine! I only can't ping it!

Look:
[image]

Any way I need to see the ping reply packet!

Comment: this should be tagged vmware and you don't say what vmware software you are using.

Comment: @gogoud Thank you. I changed the tags. _what vmware software you are using_: how many VMWare is there outside? (I even mentioned the version of VMWare).

Comment: see http://www.vmware.com/products/. You mentioned a version number but not the software...

Comment: @Archemar Sorry, that was a miswritten. Both are `10.0.0.60`. I corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: @gogoud Well, I have this problem for both virtual machines installed on `VMware® Workstation` and `VMWare VSphere` softwares.

Comment: Turn off your Windows firewall and try to use bridge mode instead of nat.

Comment: @Chris.C Thank you but I don't want to use the NAT mode.I want to solve the issue. Any way, I have the same problem for NAT too!

Comment: What happens if you say, from Kali, `ping -M dont  8.8.8.8`? Does this work?

Comment: To reduce the number of variables, turn off IPv6 on host and VM. Also on the router's internal network (if you can). Did you try another Linux distribution than Kali?

Comment: Can you provide the logfiles from the Kerio? Specifically check for "Packets dropped for some reason" ( see http://kb.kerio.com/product/kerio-control/security/troubleshooting-traffic-rules-1584.html ).
Windows and Linux ping utilities differ in a few things regarding the packets they send.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I tried `ping -M dont 8.8.8.8`. Returned nothing.

Comment: @harrymc Yes, I tried `Ubuntu` too. Same result.

Comment: @Squeezy I checked the logs, there is no dropped packet from `10.0.0.38` there!

Comment: @Squeezy Do you have any idea about the problem that I mentioned my last comment under the answer of this question: http://superuser.com/questions/997636/weirdly-i-cant-ping-my-gateway-from-linux-virtual-machines  - Gateway, returns the MAC address of its another NIC!

Comment: You haven't answered whether turning off IPv6 is an option, even just as a test?

Comment: That is too specific. Packets could be dropped on the return path as well. Can you perform a tcpdump on the gateway for both pings?

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround (or arguably a fix), disable any network offloading settings on the physical NIC on the host.

1. Open Control Panel, System, Device Manager
2. Expand "Network Adapters"
3. Double-click on your physical NIC to bring up properties.
4. Select the "Advanced" tab
5. Disable all properties with "Offload" in the name (varies by network card).

NOTE: You may want to record the initial settings should you want to revert later.

Comment: What are these offloads for?

Comment: Your Wireshark log indicated the header checksum fail may be caused by "TCP checksum offload."  Some VMware forums posts indicated that disabling the offloads may be a solution.  Did you try it?  Did it work?

Comment: Offloads move stuff that is processed on the CPU for a virtual machine onto the physical NIC, like is done for the host. It helps network performance in super high load situations but is incompatible with many consumer NICs. When having this kind of issue, it's a great thing to try and has personally worked for me a few times.

Comment: Your answer worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Try using a static IP address, even if it is static, set a static IP at no-ip.com and then try to ping that IP from both machines. Also see if you can ping the router gateway?